# How to install NUnit framework in Visual Studio 2012 when using NuGet is not an option?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nunit

How can I fully install all of the required components for NUnit in VS 2012? It seems like I have either missed some steps, or that the install documentation that I have read does not work for Visual Studio 2012.

This is what I tried:

1) I have installed the NUnit 3 Test Adapter using Extensions, as described here:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Adapter-Installation

This step seems to have worked ok.

2) I then tried to install the framework following these instructions:
http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/running-or-debugging-nunit-tests-from.html

However, when I click 'install', I get an error saying that this package requires NuGet client 2.12 or higher. Apparently, version 2.12 is not available for VS 2012; the highest supported version is 2.8. Is there any way to install this package without NuGet? None of the manual install answers that I have tried worked.
It is also unclear to me where I would download the dlls for the NUnit framework FROM if I wanted to install them without using NuGet.

Alternatively, is it possible to install NUnit 2 instead? I tried uninstalling the adapter for NUnit 3, installing the one for NUnit 2. When I went to install the framework for NUnit 2, using the above method, it just isn't there. The only option for "NUnit", other than a bunch of other adapters, runners, project loaders, etc, is the one that has the green 'n' in a circle icon that matches that of version 3.

Comment: Using Visual Studio to install NUnit from nuget.org, I see versions listed all the way back to 2.5.7. The instructions you are following in step 2 are for NUnit V2 of course.

Comment: If you want to use NUnit 3, just download and install the zip package from GitHub. Put it somewhere convenient and reference it from your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> None of the manual install answers that I have tried worked. It is
>   also unclear to me where I would download the dlls for the NUnit
>   framework FROM if I wanted to install them without using NuGet.

See [NuGet/Home/#3131](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3131). Your current `Nuget Package Manager` version 2.8 doesn't support newer versions of `Nuget` packages(Including `Nunit3` package). To resolve this issue, you can choose to upgrade VS to at least VS2013 and higher, or you may have to add the reference manually without using `Nuget`.

**To answer your original question(How to reference the package without using Nuget):**

1.For example, if you need the assemblies from `Nunit3` package with version `3.11.0`, you can download the package manually from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/3.11.0).

[image]

2.Then you'll get a `nunit.3.11.0.nupkg` file, one `xx.nupkg` file is exactly one `xx.zip` file, so we can rename it to `nunit.3.11.0.zip`,after extracting it, we can get a `lib` folder in which exists the assemblies we need.

If your project targets `.net4.5` and higher, you need the `net45` folder, if it targets `.net4.0`, you need `net40` folder... And then we only need to reference the assembly `nunit.framework.dll` in VS by `Right-click project=>Add Reference=>Browse...`.

3.And since I find there's a `NUnit.props` file in `nunit.3.11.0\build`, you may also need to unload your project and edit the `xx.csproj` to copy the content of `NUnit.props` into it. You need to add the red one into your project file(csproj):

[image]

This is the manual workaround to install the NUnit3 into your project without using Nuget. I don't recommend doing something in this way, but if you have specific reason that you can't upgrade VS2012, hope this workaround makes some help :)

**In addition:** In case you now want to use `Nunit2` instead of `Nunit3`, if you need some info about `NUnit2`, you may get some help from these two blogs: [one](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-nunit-with-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-projects.htm) and [two](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/learn-basic-unit-testing-with-vs2012-and-nunit/).

Comment: Question is asking when "nuget is NOT an option" however your answer explain how to download a Nuget package. I have same question too, except I don't have Internet access when programming in a Barn! also Enterprise policies doesn't allow linking project source code to online stuff which nuget is one of them!

Comment: The owner of this question is asking how to install the required component when Nuget manager extension is not supported in old VS2012. He wants to use Nuget package, it's just he can't use Nuget client because of limitation of VS2012. Please read the question carefully before adding your comment, for the original user: He's actually asking when using NuGet Client is not an option.